# How to add a palette color into a scatterplot graph in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, color-palette

I would like to add colors into a scatterplot graph using colors from a palette (Blues).

1. Data example

   ```
    tw = c(15000, 3000, 2500, 2000, 1500, 1500, 500)
    re.tw = c(8000, 6000, 5500, 3300, 700, 1000, 1500)
    Country = c('Argentina', 'Brasil', 'Mexico', 'Chile', 'Venezuela',   'Espana', 'EEUU')
    b = data.frame(tw,re.tw,Country)
    b$Ratio = as.integer((b$tw / b$re.tw)*1000)
   ```
2. Scatterplot

   ```
     ggplot(b, aes(x=tw, y=re.tw)) + 
     geom_point(aes(col=Country, size=Ratio)) +
     theme_minimal() +
     xlim(c(0, 15000)) + 
     ylim(c(0, 8000)) + 
     labs(subtitle="by country, final values for #Hashtag", 
     y="Tweets", 
     x="Retweets", 
    title="Twetts Vs Retweets")
   ```
3. Result using this code

[image]

4. Expected Result
   Same graph, using blue palette

Comment: This is unclear to me. Do you want to drop the colors per country? Strange, as this is in your *subtitle*. Moreover, looking at your code, it believe you have switched x and y  axes.

Comment: Since this is one of the several graphs that I created, I would like to maintain it with the same color palette (Blues), about your thought, yes I switched the name of "Tweet" and "Retweets" in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some minor changes to your code.

```
require(tidyverse)

# 1. Some values 
#Single command is usually better/simple than few commands. 
df = data.frame(tw = c(15000, 3000, 2500, 2000, 1500, 1500, 500),
               re.tw = c(8000, 6000, 5500, 3300, 700, 1000, 1500),
               Country = c('Argentina', 'Brasil', 'Mexico', 'Chile',
                           'Venezuela',   'Espana', 'EEUU')) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = (tw/re.tw)*100)


# 2. Scatterplot
df %>%
  #I find it easier to put all (or most) of the aes in one place
ggplot(aes(x = tw, y = re.tw, col = Country, size = Ratio)) + 
  geom_point() +
  #Setting the colors to palette Blues. 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlim(c(0, 15000)) + 
  ylim(c(0, 8000)) + 
  labs(subtitle="by country, final values for #Dante2018", 
       y="Tweets", 
       x="Retweets", 
       title="Twetts Vs Retweets", 
       caption = "Source: Tweets from January to April with #Dante2018")
```

More on `scale_color_brewer` you can find [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually#use-rcolorbrewer-palettes).

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055094/can-i-adjust-the-lower-limit-of-scale-color-brewer) might help you with set up one particular color for the maximum value

Comment: Thank you. I never use the package tidyverse, I am reading about that right now. You made an awesome refactor in the code, I will check every change in order to learn a little more. Again thank you.

Comment: The tidyverse package (and all the packages within it) are amazing!.
If you want to know more about the tidyverse/tidy-data approach I would have recommend reading this (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf), you can also look at this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-ss_ag2k9E&list=PLNtpLD4WiWbw9Cgcg6IU75u-44TrrN3A4) and/or look for things (mainly) by Hadley Wickham. In addition, I'm glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.